# What is the entity for my NSManagedObject?

Tags: iphone, cocoa, cocoa-touch

I have a view controller that can fetch many different types of entities from my MOC.  How can I tell what the entity is for an object of the type NSManagedObject?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`[managedObject entity]` will give you an `NSEntityDescription`. From there you can send it `-name` to get the entity's name that's a bit more user-friendly.

Comment: NSManagedObject *object = (NSManagedObject *)[locations objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSEntityDescription *entityDescr = [object entity];
NSLog(@"%@", [entityDescr name]);

throws and error... *** -[NSKnownKeysDictionary1 entity]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x3e39cc0

Comment: That's because the returned value from `[locations objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]` isn't an NSManagedObject. I bet if you NSLog that object, it won't show up as an NSManagedObject.

Comment: Hey, you're right.  It's showing as an NSDictionary.  Hmmmm.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

By calling the [entity](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObject_Class/Reference/NSManagedObject.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001171-BAJCICGE) method.

Comment: NSManagedObject *object = (NSManagedObject *)[locations objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSEntityDescription *entityDescr = [object entity];
    NSLog(@"%@", [entityDescr name]);

This throws an error... *** -[NSKnownKeysDictionary1 entity]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x3e39cc0