# Cannot assign value of type NSManagedObject to type 'Journal' (an entity)

Tags: ios, core-data

I am trying to take a single entity from an array of NSManagedObjects `var journals = [NSManagedObject]()` and display it on a details page. I currently do that by declaring a variable on the destination controller when a segue is prepared from a didSelectRow action:

```
let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: (sender as! UITableViewCell))
controller.journalToDisplay = journals[indexPath!.row]
```

In the display controller I don't have much set up yet, just this delaration:

```
var journalToDisplay: Journal?
```

which throws the error:

```
Cannot assign value of type 'NSManagedObject' to type 'Journal?'
```

Isn't journal just an NSManagedObject anyway in this case? I tried using something like:

```
var journalToDisplay: NSManagedObject as! Journal
```

But that doesn't seem to be the right way.

Comment: Which is the line throwing the error? Where you declare journalToDisplay, or instantiate it? If it's the instantiation, I think you just need to explicitly cast journals[indexPath!.row] to be a Journal object.  My guess is that it is just an array, and xcode can't guarantee the object type coming out of an array from an index accessor, since you can store objects of different types in the same array in Swift.

Comment: Is `Journal` a subclass of `NSManagedObject`?

Comment: you take the help from this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604940/what-is-the-entity-for-my-nsmanagedobject

Comment: @JakeT. -> that was it, I had to force downcast it to Journal. Thought I had tried that...

Comment: @DanielThompson Mind if I add the answer, then? I see you answered your own question, but it'd be cool to get the credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays do not implicitly know the types of the objects contained within them, so the compiler can't assign custom classes without explicitly casting the object you get from indexing the array.

Cast journals[indexPath!.row] to a Journal object so the compiler knows to treat it as such.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed as per @JakeT. 's instructions to explicitly downcast `journals[indexPath!.row]` to a Journal object,

```
controller.journalToDisplay = journals[indexPath!.row] as! Journal
```